# How to Use a Subquery in MySQL in the Where clause that is an argument to an OR operator?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am trying to filter a table for specific markets by using a subquery. I want to include all null values and exclude the markets that are included in the subquery.

```
SELECT l.market
FROM lease
WHERE l.market != ANY(SELECT market FROM market_cte) OR l.market IS NULL
```

This query isn't filtering out the markets I want to get rid of.

```
SELECT l.market
FROM lease
WHERE l.market NOT IN (SELECT id FROM market_cte) OR l.market IS NULL
```

And this created a SQL compilation error.

When I list the markets I want to exclude individually, the query works but I am trying to make it more dynamic.

```
SELECT l.market
FROM lease
WHERE l.market NOT IN (1,2,3) OR l.market IS NULL
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result, all as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: Have you tried `!= ALL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use `not exists`:

```
select market
from lease l
where not exists (select 1 from market_cte c where c.id = l.market)
```

Note that this will allow records where `market` is `null` (since, in this case, `c.id = l.market` will never be fullfilled).

Another option is to use the `left join` antipattern:

```
select l.market
from lease l
left join market_cte c on c.id = l.market
where c.id is null
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked. Can you please clarify though why in the first option that `c.id = l.market` will never be fulfilled?

Comment: @lucaswinter: because `NULL` is not equal to anything (even `NULL = NULL` is false). The only way to check for nullness is to use `IS NULL`.